# Line for line encryption in bash results in exact same hash for all lines

Tags: bash, encryption, hash

Okay I'm newish to bash, just trying to take a wordlist and spit out an MD5 hash for each line. I've managed to scape this together:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
   bash -c 'echo -n "$line" | md5sum >> hashes.txt'

done < wordlist.txt
```

But when run on this wordlist:

```
test
abcd
password
password1
p@ssphrase
banana01
cindy
lou
who
mymom
yourmom
```

I get this:

```
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  -
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  -
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  -
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  -
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  -
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  -
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  -
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  -
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  -
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  -
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  -
```

While I originally thought it may be the hash for the entire file, it doesn't match up when I try that. Furthermore, the code works exactly the same as `cat` if `bash -c 'echo -n "$line" | md5sum >> hashes.txt'` is replaced with `echo "$line"`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I feel like the problem would be obvious to anyone with experience. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using `bash -c`?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/103643/cannot-echo-hello-x-txt-even-with-sudo
Using this line for getting the hash, for some reason just plain "md5sum "test"" was not working

Comment: In that question it's needed because it uses `sudo` to write to a file that the user doesn't have access to.

Comment: You should be able to write just `echo -n "$test" | md5sum >> hashes.txt`. When I do that I get the expected result.

Comment: That works thank you

Comment: And that fixed my entire issue, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was from using `bash -c` instead of what I should have been using:

`echo -n "$test" | md5sum >> hashes.txt`

thanks Barmar in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the command line being given to `bash` is in single quotes. That prevents variables from being expanded. So the new `bash` process tries to expand the variable `$line`, but it doesn't exist in that process (variables are not inherited by other processes unless you export them to the environment). So every iteration is calculating the MD5 of an empty string.

There's no need for the subshell, just do it in the main shell process

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
   printf "%s" "$line" | md5 >> hashes.txt

done < wordlist.txt
```